# Nesting HTML- anchor tags

Tags: html, tabs, anchor

Today I was working on a tab navigation for a webpage. I tried the [Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors2/) approach which worked fine. Then I realized that I must include an option to delete a tab (usually a small X in the right corner of each tab).

I wanted to use a nested anchor, which didn't work because it is [not](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) allowed. Then I saw the tab- navigation at [Pageflakes](http://www.pageflakes.com), which was actually working (including nested hyperlinks). Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They must be doing some really crazy stuff with JavaScript to get it to work (notice how neither the parent nor the nested anchor tags have a name or href attribute - all functionality is done through the class name and JS).

Here is what the html looks like:

```
<a class="page_tab page_tab">
  <div class="page_title" title="Click to rename this page.">Click & Type Page Name</div>
  <a class="delete_page" title="Click to delete this page" style="display: block;">X</a>
</a>
```

Answer (score 17):

[Nested links are illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

Comment: Is this true of HTML 5? I don't see it. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: I see it, but it took a while to see it.  In the page you referenced:

    "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)."

Comment: @Sean In HTML5, <a> is refered as "Interactive Content". http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element saying that **"there must be no interactive content descendant"** in content model

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code I had pasted previously was the generated DOM, after all JS manipulation.  If you don't have the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) extension for Firefox, you should get it now.

Edit: Deleted the old post, it was no longer useful.  Firebug is, so this one is staying :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that working or not working nested links might depend if your browser renders page in strict mode (e.g. XHTML DTD, application/xml+html MIMEtype), or in "quirks" mode.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of nested tags are illegal but writing them using JS will work!, try this:

```
$('<a>', {
     href: 'http://google.com',
     html: '<a>i am nested anchor  </a>I am top Anchor'
 }).appendTo($('body'))
```